# How to get MAC Address of system using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, mac-address

How do I get MAC address of system using Angular, JavaScript, TypeScript or any other techniques.

I just want to store the MAC address of system for to just check whether that system used earlier or not.

Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure inside a subquery.  So the name for this is "syntax error".

Comment: Also, please post the code **here, as properly, nicely formatted text** - do **NOT** add a screenshot of your code

Comment: you can use SQL tabular Functions instead of stored Proc.

Comment: The answer is simple: you can't

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: You really ought to use meaningful aliases for your tables. `t1` through `t32` makes the code harder to read. But I also wouldn't alias a table with a 4-character name unless referring to it in a subquery or multiple times in the same query.

Comment: I'm sure you get it by now that you can't call a SP from within a subquery.   You may want to consider converting your SP to a table-valued function (TVF).  This way it can be called from a CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY

Comment: you can't do that.

Comment: Yogendra, you're not supposed to edit your question to totally change it, you have to ask another one

Comment: @baudsp
What if, you have reached maximum

Comment: If you're talking about [rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), you just wait.